# Scrolling pages one by one with mousewhell

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel, iscroll

My scroller work fine but when I use mousewheel I jump from image 1 to image 3 or 4. 
How to load ONE item at one time with scrolling/mousewheel?
I've read this

http://iscrolljs.com/#snap

to implement the method

```
myScroll.next();
```

but this work with a link, for example

```
$( "#link" ).click(function() {
myScroll.next();
});
```

but not with a mouseWheel scrolling.

Same problem on mobile (with vertical "light" ((minimum)) swipe i go to image 2, with "normal force" swipe i go to image 3 or 4). Please note that i'm using JQuery.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image4.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="image5.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var myScroll;
function loaded () {
var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
mouseWheel: true,
scrollX: true,
scrollbars: true,
momentum:false,
fade: true,
snap: 'li'
});

setTimeout( function(){
myScroll.refresh() ;
} , 200 ) ;
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
loaded();

});
```

**EDIT 1**
THis code doesn't work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var myScroll;
function loaded () {
    var myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
    mouseWheel: false,
    snapThreshold: 0.334,
    scrollbars: true,
    requestAnimationFrame: false,
    momentum:false,
    fade: true,
    snap: 'li',
    snapSpeed: 773
    });



    /* FUNCTION ***************************/
    $(function() {
        var $window = $(window);
        $window.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        //-1 scroll down, 1 scroll up
        event.preventDefault();

        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.deltaY/3 || event.originalEvent.detail;

        if (delta < 0) {
            myScroll.prev();
        }
        else if(delta > 0) {
            myScroll.next();
        }

        });
    });
    /* END FUNCTION ***************************/

    setTimeout( function(){
        myScroll.refresh() ;
    } , 200 ) ;
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

loaded();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code do what you're looking for, this event **'mousewheel DOMMouseScroll'** listen to the mouse wheel event and delta is the distance moved by scroll.

```
$(function() {
    var $window = $(window);
    $window.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
        //-1 scroll down, 1 scroll up
        event.preventDefault();

        var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 || -event.originalEvent.deltaY/3 || event.originalEvent.detail;

        if (delta < 0) {
            //scroll down
        }
        else if(delta > 0) {
            //scroll up
        }

    });
});
```